# Excel VSTO NewWorkbook event doesn't occur on startup

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm developing an Excel 2010 application-level addin. I need to write handlers for some of the Application events connected with the Workbook interface, especially NewWorkbook event.

So in ThisAddIn_Startup handler I added code like this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.AppEvents_Event app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
app.NewWorkbook += MyApp_NewWorkbook;
```

It works fine when the new Workbook is created within running Excel instance. But when I run new Excel instance (which, in standard cases, implies creating new Workbook) this event isn't catched by my handler. I suppose then that when I run new Excel instance the NewWorkbook event occurs before the ThisAddIn_Startup event.

In case of the WorkbookOpen event application behaves just like I would expect - event is catched when I open existing Workbook within the running Excel instance as well as when I just double-click the file. I'm wondering why these events are handled differently?

What should I do in this case? I need to recognize if a new Workbook was created or an existing one was opened regardless of whether Excel is already running or not.

Comment: The empty workbook template doesn't count as "opening a workbook" I think. You'll have to register some app startup event to handle that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about performing your action on all the workbooks that are open when your add-in loads?

Something like the following in the ThisAddIn_Startup handler? (no IDE here, so written by hand):

```
foreach (var workbook in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks)
{
  // Do your thing
}
```

Then use your event handling to catch any workbooks that open subsequently.

Comment: I was thinking about this solution and probably it's the only one but combined with Kiru's answer. On startup I will iterate through the collection of all Workbooks and perform my action on those which are not saved. This will eliminate the risk of handling Workbook openning twice - on startup and in WorkbookOpen event handler.

Answer (score 1):

In the WorkbookOpen event check for

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(application.ActiveWorkbook.Path)
```

which means your workbook is never saved. All the new workbook created when you open the Excel will be true for the above line.

Comment: That's ok, but it doesn't cover the case of creating new Workbook as WorkbookOpen event isn't raised then. But I can think of using this somewhere else - in startup for example :)

Comment: I will combine it with the Chris Spicer's answer, hope it will work.